# Adnetwork, ads, for windows phone 8.1 and 10 universal with phonegap / cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, publish, ads

I would like to know if someone know how add different advertising in an app of windows phone universal, do it with phonegap.
At this moment I'm working with Microsof Advertising, but the fill rate and eCPM are really low(15% and 0.32Euros approx.). I was looking for another ways and for the moment i dind't do to use another one, Admob doesn't work on universal apps, and I try others(Smaato and AdMediator), but i find that the SDK doesn't work for a Javascript project.

If someone have some experience with the implementation of another AdNetwork it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Smaato working only when I build locally for Windows Phone Universal. When I build with PhoneGap Build, it doesn't work. But Smaato doesn't pay out nearly as well as Admob used to for me for Windows Phone. Hoping they release Admob for WP Universal soon.

Here's the plugin I used for Smaato:
https://github.com/phfsantos/cordova-plugin-smaato.git

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried Smaato building locally but i didn't work.... I'm going to try as soon as possible another time. Is good to know that someone do it work. Yes, I hope too Admob soon!

Comment: @cegonzal91 or Rob did you guys ever find a good solution?  I have Admob for android and ios and was trying to implement this plugin for windows...  I could get it to display a banner, but never the correct size and the click location was always really small.  Also, could never get a video ad. I am using Angular in a Cordova app

Comment: I tried Smaato for a while, but got a pretty low payout from it (both from Smaato as well as the number of users still on Windows Phone devices). Ultimately, I've pretty much given up development on Windows Phone until there are better monetization options. I'm not sure why Admob still doesn't support WP, but my guess is WP won't be around much longer (at least in the state it is in now).

Comment: As you are saying I focus my time on android and iOS because WP for the moment is die... Also since time Admob delete totally the Ads for Windows.